# Alter the query builder from a specific model everytime - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

How do I alter the query builder everytime I'm getting a new model?

I've found that overriding the method below works, but I'm not feeling good doing this. Is there a better way to do this?

So I want `->join()` to be executed everytime for a specific model.

**!!** I don't want to use the `protected $with = [];` property, cause I don't want extra queries to be executed when not necessary.

```
public function newQueryWithoutScopes()
{
    $builder = $this->newEloquentBuilder(
        $this->newBaseQueryBuilder()
    );

    // Once we have the query builders, we will set the model instances so the
    // builder can easily access any information it may need from the model
    // while it is constructing and executing various queries against it.
    return $builder->setModel($this)->join('join statement comes here')->with($this->with);
}
```

Comment: Use Eloqunt global scopes in the Model class boot method https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#global-scopes

Answer (score 1):

To affect the query every time a model is used, you can use the newQuery method.

```
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true){
    return parent::newQuery()->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id');
}
```

But this will probably break Eloquent since your Model isn't representative of your database model anymore; it is now a Frankenmodel of two separate models.